# Multiple todo lists in a React Application (parent -> child relationships)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-orm

I have found a serious flaw I think in ReactJS.  Although I admit this flaw perhaps might be a flaw in my understanding :)  I am trying to build a simple Todo application (using TodoMVC), and when you try to use something like Redux for state managment, you run into very, very hairy issues when trying to process nested JSON, i.e. a database response that typically would include a parent node ("projects"> and then child nodes "todos") related to the parent.

Redux seems to want you to "normalize" the data from the response so it's immuatable.  Not to upset anyone, but this seems like the most ridiculous thing in the universe. So, we build a SPA app to process json responses from our data....and then...oh wait, we have to build an ORM on the client to munge all that data into a different format to process it.

If this is the state (sorry no pun intended), of React, Redux and the like, Javascript frameworks should be abandoned.  I built something in Rails in like 20 minutes. Of course it's not a SPA, but it was simple to create this MVC structure... not only does it seem extremely difficult, hairy and overly complicated in React, when Redux is added, it gets into the area of absurdity.  Perhaps that is why we only see very very simple tutorials with all these tools.... building huge apps with them isn't possible.

So basically, in just trying to code a simple few lines of this example above with react and redux, I was lead to this:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Can someone prove me wrong?  PLEASE.  Just a simple codepen showing me you can have a parent "project" component, which you can add "todos" to as children and the ability to make MULTIPLE parent components, with MULTIPLE children without going down the rabbit hole above.

This is a serious flaw in my opinion if this is true.  A showstopper.

Answer (score 1):

Your question and understanding are wrong in a few ways.

For context, I'm a Redux maintainer, and I wrote the Redux "Normalizing State Shape" docs page you linked to.

First, you don't *need* to use Redux if you're using React.  In fact, we recommend that most beginners should focus on learning React first, and only try learning Redux once they're comfortable with React.

Second, Redux is independent of React, although they're commonly used together.  You can use Redux by itself, or with any UI framework (React, Angular, Vue, Ember, jQuery, vanilla JS, etc).

Third, normalizing is a *recommended* pattern, but it's not required.  Per the docs page you linked, normalizing data has several benefits, but it's fine to keep your data nested if that works better for your application.

Fourth, there's *many* large complex apps that are written with React and Redux, not just todo examples.  See the Apps and Examples list in my [Redux addons catalog](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/apps-and-examples.md).

Both the React docs and Redux docs have links to many CodePen / CodeSandbox examples that demonstrate how to use them - see the [Main Concepts](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) and [Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#prerequisites) pages in the React docs, and the [Examples](https://redux.js.org/introduction/examples) page in the Redux docs.

Also, the TodoMVC.com site has [several React todo list examples](http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/) you can look at.

I'd suggest that you take the time to go through the tutorials in the React docs.  You may be interested in my suggested resources for [learning React](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/blogged-answers-learn-react/) and [learning Redux](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/12/blogged-answers-learn-redux/), as well as the articles and resources listed in my [React/Redux links list](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links).

Comment: Thank you for your words.  Yes, I understand, that the actual flaw is my understanding starring in The Summer of Noob.  Of course React and Redux are amazing, and I have went through Dan's tutorials on Egghead, and I understand the state tree has to be immutable.  So when JSON data comes in in a certain structure it can't be altered, because that breaks immutablability so that's not redux anymore.  So, you would have to normalize the data.  But it seems in certain applications, like mine,  normalizing a database JSON reponse just to get something to fit a pattern is not desirable.

Comment: You can put your data in the Redux store in whatever structure you want.  You can take exactly what the API response provides and put it into the store that way, or reorganize the data instead before you put it into the store.  Normalizing the data makes it easiest to apply immutable updates and look up items by ID, but if you don't want to do that, _you don't have to_.

Comment: It's doable.... but it doesn't seem elegant is what I am saying.  So you have parent todo "projects", and you can make many of these, and then you have multiple todos per project... just a very basic many to one relationship.  A very very run of the mill thing.  But in Rails, I can make two models and scaffold a controller and views and in 15 minutes I have an application that works, that takes react, redux, normalizer, thunk, and lots of others to accomplish this with dozens of files and props/state being passed.

Comment: It seems flawed to me to maintain state on the front-end this way.  it seems like the state should be passed back and forth between the server backend and maintained there and hydrated down via JSON and make the front-end more dumb.   Just my thoughts.  Again though....noob thoughts.

Comment: No.  No, you don't.  You're conflating way too many things here.  If you want to have a single `state.projects` array full of project objects, and nest an array of todos for that project inside those, you can. And how you structure the data in your Redux store is totally separate from how you organize your source files, or how you write your async logic.

Comment: Overall, it seems to me that the real stumbling point here is viewing things from a backend developer's mindset, vs a client-side developer's view.  Both are valid viewpoints, but it seems that client-side dev is new to you.  I'd suggest simplifying things.  Go through the React tutorials, learn how to use it in a simple way, then build from there. Don't use Redux for now. Just React, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your advice and words.  I will do this!  You are correct.  I do not completely understand the power of React, just coming from Vanilla Javascript and Rails.  Thanks!  :)

Comment: Sure :) Learning to "think in React" is always a jump for people coming from a client-side jQuery background, so I'd figure it's even more of a jump for someone who is used to doing everything on the server.  In addition to those resource links, I'd encourage you to come by the Reactiflux chat channels on Discord, where there's always a bunch of people happy to answer questions.  The invite link is at https://reactiflux.com .